# Add items from combobox to Listview and Start doing items in ListView

Tags: c#, listview, button

For better explanation here is a GUI  screenshoot :

[image]

And here is a all of my code with comments :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media; // to play sounds


namespace Music_PLayer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //List View
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

            // Columns CONSTRUCT
            listView1.Columns.Add("ID", 70);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Music name", 150);

            //combobox  items
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 1");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 2");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 3");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 4");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 5");
        }

        // ADD TO List VIEW
        private void add(int ID, string name_music)
        {
            string[] row = { Convert.ToString(ID), name_music };

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);

            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }

        //button to delete selected items in list view
        private void button_delete_selected_music_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                listView1.SelectedItems[0].Remove();
            }
            catch { }

        }

        // buttton to add music to list view
        int i = 0;
        private void button_add_music_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            add(i, comboBox1.Text);
                i++;

        }

        // button to start music
        private void button_start_music(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        // Voids with music :
        public void playmusic1()
        {

            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound1);
            audio.Play();
        }
        public void playmusic2()
        {
            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound2);
            audio.Play();
        }
        public void playmusic3()
        {
            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound3);
            audio.Play();

        }
        public void playmusic4()
        {
            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound4);
            audio.Play();
        }
        public void playmusic5()
        {
            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound5);
            audio.Play();
        }
         public class dataItem
    {
        public string shortName { get; set; }
        public string longName { get; set; }
        public dataItem(string s, string l) { shortName = s; longName = l; }
        public override string ToString() { return shortName; }
    }


    }
}
```

I want to to select a song from the combobox to add it to the playlist that will play from top to bottom after clicking on the "Start Music" button..

I would like to add a selected song from the combobox to the listview when you click the "Add Music to list" button. Of course, with the "Delete selected music" button I have the ability to delete a song from the list.

So I have to do so for example when I select from the combobox (Music1) click on the button (Add Music to list), it will display ID 1 Music name Music 1 and when click on the Start Music button it will execute void playmusic1 ();

I know I just only add text from combobox to listview but i don't know how can I get method there...

I really don't know how to code Start Music button to play music one by one with my listView1.

All I need is Collection or something or Queue.

If I dont explain exacly just ask..

Comment: Look into combobox.selecteditem ! Also: If the display string is not enough to find/play the file you can add the full path in the item's Tag property..

Comment: When you add a collection object use AddRange() instead of Add().  So it would be listView1.Items.AddRange(array);

Comment: Adding all items would not make any sense. Only the one item  selected/shown in the combbox should be added..  his problem seems to be how to play the music. If that is so the question has a wrong title!

Comment: @TaW 100% true, anyway can you help me a bit more? Do you know how  to edit my code to work ? . I think you  understand code and my program function and you know what i mean and im trying to do

Comment: I was wrong in my 1st comment: Items in a combobox are objects. And while you can add simple strings you cannot attach a Tag to them. So you need to pick some other route. The cleanest is to create a simple class with two strings, one holding a display name and one the full path. Add in a ToString override and a constructor and you are ready to flll the Combobox. Then you can cast the SelectedIiem and add create a ListViewItem from the short text, adding the data obkject in the tag...

Comment: ..In the play button you can pull out the listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag as dataItemClass and send the long text to a player routine. Here is a minimal data class: `public class dataItem
    {
        public string shortName { get; set; }
        public string longName { get; set; }

        public dataItem(string s, string l)
        { shortName = s; longName = l; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return shortName;
        }
    `

Comment: could you write an example based on my code?

Comment: @Up just added your class to main code. Can you just give an answear and give me example that what i need to do?